# Retrieve google sheets data synchronously to android app

Tags: java, android, database, google-sheets

I'm searching a solution for getting google sheets data into android app. I found some tutorials but most of them not relevant because of current google Auth limitations and the others forcing me publish the sheet itself to the web and losing the privacy, which i don't t want.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `current google Auth limitations` what exactly are the limitations that bothers you for your particular use case? What kind of authorisation do you expect to be the ideal for your use case?

Comment: There’s a problem getting the data from the sheet it self without publishing it to the internet before. I read that it was possible few years ago and now it’s not because of google auth limitations. I’m not very familiar with google sheets so forgive me for the lack of explanation.